# #Zabbix, extract all values from a file

Tags: snmp, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I have several files located on a host, that i would like to graph and trigger them
I played around with the parameter. 
It seems to read the content of the file. but I fail to capture the separate values in the file and graph them.

the value at the end of the line is no problem :)

the example contents of the file is this :

```
OK
OK: 48007.699 8.666 6.332 9.825 | sr=48007.699 lt=8.666 pd=6.332 md=9.825 sd=-0.033081 
dgrams 65514798 missing 184359 excessive 257 late 37423
```

I would like to capture the following values after the "="

```
sr=48007.699
lt=8.666
pd=6.332
md=9.825
sd=-0.033081
```

and the values behind the text

```
dgrams 65514798
missing 184359
excessive 257
late 37423
```

I run the zabbix agent on the host

I am currently using the "vfs.file.regexp" method.

Answer (score 0):

It looks nearly impossible in Zabbix, you should write a script to parse these values and send them to Zabbix.

Comment: Yes Dmitry that was my conclusion also. I wil try to extract the values by running a script and then do the collection by zabbix.